# Symfony entity validation won't report violation

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I am trying to add some validation to my entity, using the Symfony validation component, i have added some constraints to my User Entity.

```
/**
 * @param ClassMetadata $metadata
 */
public static function loadValidatorMetadata(ClassMetadata $metadata)
{
    $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('username', new Assert\NotBlank);
    $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('password', new Assert\NotBlank);
    $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('first_name', new Assert\NotBlank);
    $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('last_name', new Assert\NotBlank);
}
```

Now i want to test if i get some errors, when violating the constraints, this is done like this.

```
    $user = new User();
    $user->username = '';
    $user->password = '';

    $validator = Validation::createValidator();

    if (0 < count($validator->validate($user))) {
        throw new \RuntimeException('The given user is invalid');
    }
```

But the count is zero, which is odd, as all the constraints is clearly violated? Am i missing something here? Well i must be :D.

Might be worth to notice, that my application is not a Symfony application; it's a ordinary php application, i am just using the component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [specify which methods act as mapping methods](https://github.com/symfony/Validator/blob/7630728e4436a2937e96ada41a636dc111923a05/ValidatorBuilder.php#L183-L192):

```php
$validator = Validation::createValidatorBuilder()
    ->addMethodMapping('loadValidatorMetadata')
    ->getValidator()
```